# Is there an adjective that means "far-deviating"?

Tags: word-request

There are adjectives that are synonymous with deviating, but I'm wondering if there are synonyms for the compound adjective "far-deviating", which can be useful to express certain ideas. It's not often used, but I feel there's something here that could be useful in everyday speech.

For example:

> His intelligence was extremely high. In fact, it was far-deviating
>   from the average of his age group.
>
> She was deeply deranged. Her derangement was far-deviating from the
>   norm, so that they decided to seclude her from other patients.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In statistics, a deviation far from the mean is known as an **outlier**.

Per Merriam-Webster,

> outlier: a statistical observation that is markedly different in value
>   from the others of the sample.

You'll see it has several other uses and is not limited to statistical contexts.